# The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all() while running sort_values in a loop

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, jupyter-notebook

I am running a for loop inside a function in python Jupyter notebook. I keep getting an annoying error which I am unable to figure out the cause for it. When the for loop is removed, the code works fine for individual skill id. However, when a loop is run the error occurs.

```
def create_recommendations():
   recommendations_final_data_US = pd.DataFrame()
   for i in range(all_skill_ids.size):
         idx = indices[all_skill_ids[i]]
         sim_scores = list(enumerate(cosine_sim2[idx]))
         x = pd.DataFrame(sim_scores)
         x.columns = ['skill_indice', 'similarity_score']
         x.sort_values('similarity_score', ascending=False, inplace=True)
         skill_indices = x[1:11]['skill_indice']
         recommendation = metadata['skill_id'].iloc[skill_indices]
         recommendation = recommendation.reset_index()
         recommendation = recommendation.drop(columns='index')
         final_recommendations = pd.merge(recommendation, ratings, on='skill_id', how='inner')
         final_recommendations = final_recommendations.sort_values(by='average_rating_score',ascending=False)
         final_recommendations_skill_id = final_recommendations['skill_id']
         for recommended_skill in final_recommendations_skill_id:
                  recommendations_final_data_US = recommendations_final_data_US.append({'skill_id': skill_id, 'recommended_skill_id': recommended_skill}, ignore_index=True)
         return recommendations_final_data_US
```

Full error code:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-269-36b9236d057a> in <module>()
----> 1 final = create_recommendations()

<ipython-input-268-06eee9a60281> in create_recommendations()
      6         x = pd.DataFrame(sim_scores)
      7         x.columns = ['skill_indice', 'similarity_score']
----> 8         x.sort_values('similarity_score', ascending=False, inplace=True)
      9         skill_indices = x[1:11]['skill_indice']
     10         recommendation = metadata['skill_id'].iloc[skill_indices]

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in sort_values(self, by, axis, ascending, inplace, kind, na_position)
   3632 
   3633             indexer = nargsort(k, kind=kind, ascending=ascending,
-> 3634                                na_position=na_position)
   3635 
   3636         new_data = self._data.take(indexer,

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/sorting.py in nargsort(items, kind, ascending, na_position)
    248         non_nans = non_nans[::-1]
    249         non_nan_idx = non_nan_idx[::-1]
--> 250     indexer = non_nan_idx[non_nans.argsort(kind=kind)]
    251     if not ascending:
    252         indexer = indexer[::-1]

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

It would be great if someone could help me!

Comment: `argsort` is doing comparisons such as `a>b`.  But it `a` and/or `b` is a numpy array, the comparison will be a boolean array, with a `True/False for each element of the arrays.  It can't then unambiguously say whether `a` is > than `b` or not.  This error is produced when `numpy` or `pandas` produces a boolean array in a context that requires a scalar True/False.  Look at all the `Related` questions in the side bar.

Comment: @hpaulj Sorry, but unable to understand the actual cause. Could you please elaborate based on my code. I checked every related question :-(

Comment: I'm guessing it has to with nature of the 'similarity_score' column of `x`, but you haven't told us anything about that.  You haven't given us any kind of sample data that would let us reproduce your problem.  [mcve]

Comment: skill_indice similarity_score
 302         1.000000
 3535 0.760639
 20846 0.755929
 17895 0.740744
 7089 0.740744
 2664 0.735767
6 3708 0.725241
7 20713 0.725241
8 11958 0.707107
9 9765 0.707107

Comment: sorry @hpaulj, above is the data frame which holds the skill indices and similarity score. Also, my loop runs perfectly for "for i in range(31)". After 30 runs, it fails

Comment: why are you looping on size? size here is m x n where m is your rows and n is your columns. And if you're looping in a column, size will produce error when it will exceed the length of your dataframe.

Comment: @JackDaniels Hi, there is only one column, and the count is picked up correctly by the size keyword. However, I removed that and manually tried a number. It seems, beyond 31, the loop failed with the original error that I am getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. found some duplicate ids which was causing this issue. Thanks all for your advice!